# Lambda Expression with &&

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to construct a lambda expression with "&&" but am getting an error that says:

Error   CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected

Here is my code.

```
   using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            string candidateResult = candidatedetails[0].ToString();
            string fileResult = candidatedetails[1].ToString();

            var list = db.Table<Candidates>().ToList();

            var cand = db.Table<Candidates>().Where(p => p.CandidateName == candidateResult && p => p.FileIdentification == fileResult);
            foreach (Candidates can in cand)
            {
                string[] FileIDSplit = can.FileIdentification.Split('_');
                CandidateName = can.CandidateName;
                CandidateParty = can.CandidateParty;
                ElectionYear = FileIDSplit[0];
                ElectionType = FileIDSplit[1];
                Race = FileIDSplit[2];
            }
        }
```

The error occurs at the second "p=>p."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to specify the lambda input variable (`p =>`) once, the right hand side is just an expression and can use the input `p` at will

```
...Where(p => p.CandidateName == candidateResult && p.FileIdentification == fileResult);
```

---

[Lambda expressions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

> To create a lambda expression, you specify input parameters (if any)
>   on the left side of the lambda operator =>, and you put the expression
>   or statement block on the other side

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
p => p.CandidateName == candidateResult && p.FileIdentification == fileResult
```